# Set ACFacebookAudienceKey while posting on facebook

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using below code for post on my wall programatically. Code works perfectly, just problem is that while posting on `Facebook` it always set `ACFacebookAudienceKey` as `Friends`. Can any one pleas tell me how i can set it programmatically. I don't wanna use code for posting that show me `Facebook` share or post dialog. I think i need to add `PublishPermissions` on login, but did't know exactly how i can achieve my functionality.

Thanks

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   let loginButton = LoginButton(readPermissions: [ .publicProfile,.email,.userFriends])
   loginButton.center = view.center
   loginButton.delegate = self
   view.addSubview(loginButton)
 }

func post() {
   if FBSDKAccessToken.current().hasGranted("publish_actions") {
       FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me/feed", parameters: ["message" : "Posted with FBSDK Graph API.", ACFacebookAudienceKey : ACFacebookAudienceEveryone], httpMethod: "POST").start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
         if let error = error {
             print("Error: \(error)")
          } else {
              print("Message")
           }
        })
    } else {
         print("require publish_actions permissions")
    }
 }
```

Comment: Go to https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications and check what default visibility you have set for this app. If you change this to public, that might be enough already.

Comment: @CBroe thanks it works, but i need to handle it from code.

Comment: Well then you have to specify the `privacy` parameter with your post data, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed#publish (don’t ask me how that works with your specific SDK though.) Plus, you can not select a broader privacy value than the aforementioned default value - you can only use this parameter to further narrow it down, but not to widen it beyond what the user has in their settings.